# Strange result with Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel

Hi I'm using this addon for laravel and when I export to excel I get a lot of strange characters, I think its because im getting the father of any var, here is the code

```
 $data= [$result,$orderView,$arrayOrder];
    Excel::create('Report', function ($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->loadView('globalreport.excel')
                ->with('result', $data[0])->with('order', $data[1])->with('tabla', $data[2]);
        });
    })->download('xls');
```

And this is the view for make excel

```
<table class="table" id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    @foreach ($tabla as $ord)
        <th>{{$ord}}</th>
    @endforeach
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach ($result as $res)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($order as $ord)
            <td>{{$res->$ord}}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach

</tbody>
```

The result is some like this

ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ   þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿ

!"#$%&'þÿÿÿ)*+þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿà…ŸòùOh«‘+'³Ù0¨@HXpˆ

” äReportUnknown CreatorUnknown Creator@€ã-xwÐ@€ã-xwÐ   »

ÌÑB°=¼%r8X"1ÜCalibri1ð¼Calibriàõÿ À àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   àõÿ À   à À à È
MY DATA

    »

ÌÑ*+‚€Áƒ„&'()¡" dXX333333Ó?333333Ó?U}d}þ}‘ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
    ý

ý
ý
ý

ý
ý
ý
ý

> ¶@d‹‹dggÿÿÿÿÿ
>   þÿÕÍÕœ.“—+,ù®0¼HPX`hp
>   xŽä
>   WorksheetFeuilles de calculRoot Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÀFz¯-xwÐz¯-xwÐSummaryInformation(ÿÿÿÿ   ÀFØWorkbookÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÀFëDocumentSummaryInformation8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  ÀF(ìþÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and the problem was some spaces before the "<?php" tag in the routes.php file. Just remove the spaces and that's it!

Comment: Do you have any idea why and how this happens?

Comment: I had the same issue and it was a space before the "<?php" tag. Tried checking and couldn't find any substantial reason for that. Can anyone tell why?